# markdown on work computer and installing tinytex

Tags: r

I'm trying to get rmarkdown to work on my windows work computer.

When trying to install tinytex I get the following error. What can I do to solve this?

```
tinytex::install_tinytex()
  
Error:
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
Error in download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  'curl' call had nonzero exit status

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
2: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip': status was 'SSL connect error'
3: In download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
```

Comment: Can you access the https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip URL from your work computer? It sounds like you might have some sort of network firewall that's blocking that URL. If you contact your IT staff with that particular problem they are more likely to be able to help than we are.

Comment: This github issue has some suggestions that might help, such as installing the prebuilt version (`tinytex:::install_prebuilt()`) or addressing ssl/curl flags: https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/225#issuecomment-660974962